# App for kids tracing out words, with clues, even in cursive script

Tags: educational, accessibility, transcription, writing, screenwriting

I am looking for an app for Android smartphones for five year olds that have mastered letters and must now learn how to write out words, also as part of sentences, in cursive script.

Ideally, the app would be divided in two parts. The top part, would present a grid with squares, each of which would contain a letter from a sentence to be displayed. The sentence is displayed in medium blue purple script, and turns bright red as the user writes out the words.

The words, are displayed, centered on the current letter and displaying parts of the adjoining letters via links in light purple below. This is in fact the second section of the app, where the user is not able to just read the smaller letters from the top part of the sentence, but trace them out, one letter at a time, in larger letter script.

There is also a voice part to the app, and two time sequence parts to the app.

In the first time part of the app:

LOOP I

- The app displays a sentence, in the top part.
- The app reads the sentence aloud.

LOOP J

- The app reads the current word, starting from the first word.

LOOP K

- The app reads the first letter of the word.
- The user traces out the letter.
- The user interface makes a positive sound clue for correct tracing, or a negative sound clue for incorrect tracing, in which case the trace is cancelled and the user must trace the letter again.
- The medium blue purple script for the letter in the top part of the app turns red.
- The screen advances, through scrolling, the current letter to be written.

---

In the second time part of the app (which can be accessed through a special gray "trace without cues" button at the bottom of the app, which turns green upon completion of the first part):

This is the same as the first part of the app, but this time without cues. Only the whole sentence is read once, then the user must trace the letters in the bottom part without seeing them in the top part. Only when they make a mistake is the next current word repeated, perhaps with the repetition also available with the aid of, a button which repeats the current word, and another button which can be selected to repeat the whole sentence.

The user traces the sentence out.

As part of a gaming expedice, the user that traces the sentence faster and correctly with fewer mistakes hearing the words (or sentence) through pressing the corresponding buttons less times, earns more points.

............

The sentences get more complicated and longer, as the user progresses, but The length and difficulty is not increased very much, as the users are young, and the user can pause the app though any given progress (or also repeat parts), at any given time.

...........

The letters are displayed in calligraphic mode. The user, between each letter (for scripts, such as Latin script), where the letters adjoin, a way to trace from the previous letter to the next letter continuously, and the app must admit a way for the user to trace continuously the continuation between scripting the previous letter and adjoining the next letter in writing in cursive script.

So, in cursive mode, when the next letter is read, the user must not only trace the next letter, but also the part of the script that adjoins the previous letter with the next (some users have some trouble with this part, and it is important that the app reinforces it).

Perhaps, cursive mode can be selected separately, though the app preferences.

Thank you for your help.

Thank you for your support.

This would be a great app, and would be greatly educational.

And also be available on smartphones besides on tablets to support kids that were too poor to afford a tablet or did not have one.

Thanks.

Where can I download such an app.

Is there any on the Google Play store?

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

This app could profit from more lessons in more advanced levels, in which case, each parent, could pay for their child, for app usage, in case the app was not free, but I think it would be better if funds from educational institutions or support for them with funds raised were carried out to support even the poorer kids.

Thanks.